# Multiply all and only numeric values of dataframe using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe stu_alcol looks like following:

```
school  sex age address famsize Pstatus Medu    Fedu    Mjob    Fjob    reason  guardian
0   GP  F   18  U   GT3 A   4   4   at_home teacher course  mother
1   GP  F   17  U   GT3 T   1   1   at_home other   course  father
2   GP  F   15  U   LE3 T   1   1   at_home other   other   mother
3   GP  F   15  U   GT3 T   4   2   health  services    home    mother
4   GP  F   16  U   GT3 T   3   3   other   other   home    father
```

Goal is to multiply all integer values with 10 (playing with data)

This code however throws 'invalid syntax' error

```
stu_alcol.transform(lambda x: x*10 if isinstance(x, int))
```

Can anyone help?
Please understand that I am aware of other possible solutions. I just want to understand what can be possibly wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the columns by name and multiply them by a value.

```
stu_alcol[['age', 'Medu', 'Fedu']] *= 10
# stu_alcol[['age', 'Medu', 'Fedu']] = stu_alcol[['age', 'Medu', 'Fedu']]*10
# stu_alcol[['age', 'Medu', 'Fedu']] = stu_alcol[['age', 'Medu', 'Fedu']].multiply(10)
```

All three examples give the same result but using different notations.

**Comment**

You can perform a `apply()` function to all rows like below:

```
stu_alcol = stu_alcol.apply(lambda x: [xx*10 if isinstance(xx,int) else xx for xx in x])
```

but this is not easy to read and can have some performance problems.

Comment: Thank you! The apply( ) function worked and I found it more flexible. Individually selecting columns will also work. But when there are many columns, it will get strenuous.

Answer (score 2):

You can update the entire df to numeric, and let 'coerce' conver the non-numerics to NaN. Multiply that by 10 and update the original df.

This should allow you to handle mixed-type columns properly as well.

```
df.update(df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').mul(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is that a lambda function can only have one expression. Your `if` makes the lambda function more than one expression, hence the 'invalid syntax' error.

You would have to make the lambda function a single expression, for example by making it its own function, to correct the error (also note that the type that you probably want to be checking for is `numpy.int64` not `int`).

As an example, the following will work (although the `mult_ints_by_10` function is just some example code to make the point, and certainly isn't optimised!)

```
def mult_ints_by_10(data_series):
    return_series = data_series.copy()
    for loop in range(len(data_series)):
        element = data_series[loop]
        return_series[loop] = element * 10 if isinstance(element, numpy.int64) else element
    return return_series

stu_alcol.transform(lambda x: mult_ints_by_10(x))
```

Comment: Thank you! I now understand why that piece of code did not work.